# How to search data with This Week, This month, This Year in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hi i want to search data from MySql table with This Week, This month, This Year..
Below is my Controller Code.
I am not getting any data with Current `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK`

**Controller initial Code:**

```
 $condition = array('Order.eventid' => $id, 'Order.userid !=' => '');
            if (isset($_GET['dr']) && !empty($_GET['dr'])) {

                if ($_GET['dr'] == 2) { // This week 
                    $condition['Order.addeddate'] = 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)';
                }
                if ($_GET['dr'] == 3) { // This month 
                    $condition['Order.addeddate'] = 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)';
                }
                if ($_GET['dr'] == 4) { // This year 
                    $condition['Order.addeddate'] = 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)';
                }
                if ($_GET['dr'] == 5) { //  Custom date range 
                    //$condition[] = array('Order.addeddate' => 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)');
                }
            }
     if (isset($_GET['ot']) && !empty($_GET['ot'])) {
                if ($_GET['ot'] == 'attending') { //attending 
                    $condition['Order.orderstatus'] = '1';
                }
                if ($_GET['ot'] == 'processing') { //online_sales 
                    $condition['Order.orderstatus'] = '2';
                }
                if ($_GET['ot'] == 'manual') { //manual 
                    $condition['Order.orderstatus'] = '1';
                }
                if ($_GET['ot'] == 'refunded') { //refunded 
                    $condition['Order.orderstatus'] = '1';
                }
            }
    $this->paginate = array(
                'conditions' => $condition
            );
```

[image]

Comment: Have you heard of the CakePHP DateTime helper? I am assuming you are using Cake 2.x? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper::daysAsSql
If you use it in the view it is TimeHelper, if you use it in the controller it is DateTime.

Comment: This does not look like CakePHP at all. You need to read the documentation on how to use request data properly. Also read about PRG pattern and how lots of this logic can be put in the model layer where it belongs using plugins like https://github.com/CakeDC/search .

Answer (score 6):

You can do it easily by use `StartDate` and `EndDate`. Add the condition like this

```
'conditions' => array('date(YourModel.addeddate) BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($sdate,$edate)
```

Now the question how you will get `this month` `this week` `this year`. You can use this below code.

You can use `cakephp TimeHelper`

**By using cakephp TimeHelper**

For get this week

```
$sdate = $this->Time->format('y-m-d','last saturday');
$edate = $this->Time->format('y-m-d',time());
```

For get this month

```
$sdate = $this->Time->format('y-m-01',time());
$edate = $this->Time->format('y-m-d',time());
```

For get this year

```
$sdate = $this->Time->format('y-01-01',time());
$edate = $this->Time->format('y-m-d',time());
```

For details [TimeHelper Doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#timehelper)

**Without TimeHelper**

For get this week

```
$sdate = date('y-m-d', strtotime("last saturday"));
$edate = date("y-m-d");
```

For get this month

```
$sdate = date('y-m-01');
$edate = date("y-m-d");
```

For get this year

```
$sdate = date('y-01-01');
$edate = date("y-m-d");
```

Now if you want to get last 7 days or last 30 days, you can use `strtotime`.

For get last 7 days

```
$sdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 weeks"));
$edate = date("y-m-d");
```

For get last 30 days

```
$sdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-30 days"));
$edate = date("y-m-d");
```

For get last 1 year

```
$sdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 year"));
$edate = date("y-m-d");
```

I think now you can easily solve your problem.

Comment: Hi , can you please again check your date format ? it seems there is some thing wrong with your $sdate and $edate format.

Comment: Which procedure are you trying ? By cakephp time helper ?What's your error message ?

Comment: Without time helper. No error but no any result. Let me check again.

Comment: date("y-m-d"); use this date format. Because your have been used this date format in your database.I am going to edit my ans.

Comment: $sdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last saturday"));
 $edate = date("Y-m-d"); 
This should be format for MySql Between clause.

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditions like below

```
//current month
$conditions = array('MONTH(Model.field) = MONTH(CURDATE())', 'YEAR(Model.field) = YEAR(CURDATE())');

//current week
$conditions = array('YEARWEEK(Model.field,1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)');
//current year
$conditions = array('YEAR(Model.field) = YEAR(CURDATE())');
```